# Inline Video Player in Facebook Bug

Tags: facebook, flash, apache-flex, video, inline

I have created a player its in early stages though, but I need to play the videos inside Facebook timeline like youtube does. I have placed my tags as following:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Little Cast Video Test"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Little Cast Video Test"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="270"/>
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="480"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://littlecast.confiz.com/littlecast/fbtest.html"/>
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://littlecast.confiz.com/littlecast/main.swf">
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://littlecast.confiz.com/littlecast/main.swf">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://littlecast.confiz.com/littlecast/thumb.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Facebook debugger is also showing that there is no bug/warning in this page but still the player is not showing and not playing inline to facebook.

Do I need to get my player approved from facebook or should it be working as is?

PS: My player is written in Flex. If you need to check the html host file please hit this url: [My URL](http://littlecast.confiz.com/littlecast/fbtest.html)

Comment: app_id tag was missing so now fb is showing it as a video, but when I click on the video, its not loading my video player. Do I have to get my player approved or what?

Comment: Thanx for viewing the question. I solved it by myself. :)

Comment: Ali how did you solve this? Can you please help?

Comment: My video is posted but it does not run. Instead the player gives a download file link..